# Lambda => event handlers in using block

Tags: c#, events, lambda, using

Say I have this code which uses multiple `lambda expressions` within `using-blocks`.

I've read one should unsubscribe event handlers due to possible `memory leaks`.

- Is it necessary to do this in `using-blocks` since `using` makes sure the object(s) gets disposed?
- Is coding this way a bad practice? (I find it handy because it keeps everything together instead of having a class filled with different event handlers

  ```
  using (BackgroundWorker w = new BackgroundWorker())
  {
      w.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
      w.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

      w.ProgressChanged += (f, g) =>
      {
          pbExport.Maximum = (int)g.UserState;
          pbExport.Value = g.ProgressPercentage;
      };
      w.RunWorkerCompleted += (c, d) =>
      {
          if ((!d.Cancelled) && ((bool)d.Result))
          {
              MSG.Text = "Backup completed !";
          }
          else
          {
              MSG.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
              MSG.Text = "Error";
          }
      };
  w.DoWork += (a, b) =>
      {
          using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(Statics._CS))
          {
              try
              {
                  cn.Open();
                  using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
                  {
                      cmd.Connection = cn;
                      using (MySqlBackup mb = new MySqlBackup(cmd))
                      {
                          mb.ExportInfo.IntervalForProgressReport = 50;
                          mb.ExportProgressChanged += (h, i) =>
                              {
                                  w.ReportProgress(i.CurrentTableIndex, i.TotalTs);
                              };
                          mb.ExportToFile("dbbackup");
                       }
                  }
                  b.Cancel = false;
                  b.Result = true;
              }
              catch (MySqlException)
              {
                  b.Cancel = true;
                  b.Result = false;
                  w.CancelAsync();
              }
          }
      };
      w.RunWorkerAsync();
  }
  ```

Comment: "I've read one should unsubscribe event handlers due to possible memory leaks." - That depends very much on the context. I wouldn't call it a general rule. The "memory leaks" due to event subscriptions is unfortunately ones of these things which is more repeated than understood.

Answer (score 3):

This looks wrong. The `using` block will call `Dispose` right after the call to `RunWorkerAsync` while the thread is still executing.

Comment: Then why is this code working perfectly? I get no exceptions.

Comment: Just because it works perfectly now does not mean it always will. The scheduling of async methods is largely out of your control.

Comment: It works because you are not checking BackgroundWorker.CancellationPending in DoWork code, despite you declared that DoWork supports cancellation. Depending on call timing, your DoWork code could not be executed at all.

Answer (score 1):

I use lambdas like this to start with and the refactor them to methods as soon as the complexity grows. There are some problems with this code, but IMHO there is nothing inherently wrong in using lambdas like this as it is quite readable.

1. You dont need the `using`. Since you only start the `BackgroundWorker` and do not wait for it to complete, the using will attempt to `Dispose()` the it while it is still running. It may be that something else has a reference to w and keeps it alive, but then you've missed your opportunity to clean up anyway.
2. Any attempt to use *Edit and Continue* inside a lambda while debugging will fail. If you took the opportunity to switch your lambdas to methods, this wouldn't happen.
3. I think your use of lambdas for `ProgressChanged` and the inner `ExportProgressChanged` are just about prefect, but that `RunWorkerCompleted` is at the maximum end of the size of code I'd expect. In my opinion is that `DoWork` is too large to be left as a lambda. Refactor it to a method.

Finally, there is a great opportunity here to refactor what you have into a `SqlBackupWorkerWithProgress`. That would solidify the use of your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 foreach(var eventHandler in MyEvent)
    eventHandler.Dispose()
```

- Disposing of a resource is always the resource holder's responsibility; it is the responsibility of the event holder to make sure it's event handlers are properly disposed (see above)
- I would not use such large inline functions for events, I would prefer to create a separate function. Large lambdas are an eyesore.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use using block for BackgroundWorker this way. In your sample worker will be disposed right after RunWorkerAsync call, possibly causing background processing to stop.

Declare a property to keep reference to BackgroundWorker alive. Dispose worker and set property to null in RunWorkerCompleted handler.

Memory leak could occur because event provider keeps a reference to event subscriber, causing event subscriber not to be garbage collected while event provider is alive.

In that specific sample there is no need to unsubscribe from events because subscriber (form/code that handles events) should live longer than background worker.

Answer (score 0):

If your lambdas aren't used/referenced/closured on outside the scope of using (or a wider local variables scope), then they will not cause a memory leak.

Memory leak is caused when you do things backwards - you create an object, reference it (and enclosure on it) in lambda, which then is added (and referenced by) to an event handler.

I.e. any object with event handlers holds references to all the labmdas in its events handlers, and in turn holds references to all the objects referenced in those lambdas.